# WSO2 Apim 4.1.0 Message Mediator not found in Runtime Api Configuratios

Tags: linux, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm really strugling with this one.
I have a distributed WSO2 api manager, no subscription, open source, version, where I need to enable one api to have a header passtru to the backend, so, I went to the official documentation and found a really simple solution:
In the publisher portal, in Api configuration, inside runtime, click on the edit button on "message mediation"
problem:
there's no message mediation block in that configuration, i have a simple, plain rest api

I'm missing something? i have really look into the documentation, but found nothing about my case

I'd tried creating new API's, looking in forums, looking for different documentations, versions, etc, nothing about enabling the message mediators policies

Answer (score 0):

In APIM 4.1.0, Message mediation is moved to **Policies** section in the API. You can apply mediation sequences from the policies section as request, response and fault policies.

Please refer the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/api-policies/attach-policy/).